# Should I message the editor when it's been 1 and half month without any response?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have submitted a review paper in a scientific journal the paper in stuck in a state of "under review" for half an month should i politely message the editor asking what is going on?

Comment: Ask a colleague what a normal turnaround time is for reviews in your field. I am willing to bet it isn't less than a month for journal papers. Then *at least* double that before you start messaging the editor.

Comment: My record is three years from submitting the manuscript to getting the (rather poor quality) review (singular).

Answer (score 1):

For context, in my field getting a response within half a *year* would be considered very fast, within three quarters of a year "normal", an entire year longish but still reasonable. The best response you are going to get is a "revise and resubmit", which means that you need to somehow implement the suggestions from the reviewers, which takes time, and than the entire cycle of getting reviews starts over again. So you should budget about two years to get an article published.